# Failed to load source map for vue-toast-notification nuxt 3

Tags: vite, toast, nuxt3

I'm using Nuxt 3 and i added vue-toast-notification, version 3.
I made a plugin to register and customize it, but my global options does'nt apply on it.

It's my toast.js file:

plugins/01.toast.js

`import { useToast } from 'vue-toast-notification';`
`import 'vue-toast-notification/dist/theme-default.css';`

`export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {`
`const toast = useToast()`
`const app = nuxtApp.vueApp`
`app.use(toast, {`
`position: 'top-right',`
`pauseOnHover: true,`
`duration: 5000`
`})`
`return {`
`provide: {`
`toast,`
`}`
`}`
`})`

when I run the project, it warns me : Failed to load source map for vue-toast-notification
I think source map is the cause of this issue.

I add sourcemap key with server and client options in nuxt.config.ts, but it didn't make any change

Do you have any idea what should i do to set my global options ?

Thank you in advance for sharing your thoughts with me.

Comment: The warning about the failed source map for vue-toast-notification might not be directly related to your issue. It's more of a warning about not being able to load the source map file. You can generally ignore this warning

Comment: So what could be related to not applying? @AdekunleCodez

Answer (score 0):

You can not use plugins to register a composable into nuxt. What you should do is you should register the toastification plugin and its composable in different files under relevant folders (plugins and composables). Also toastification plugin may cause errors on server side, so you might need to register the plugin for client side only by adding a .client extension to its name.

/plugins/toast-notification.client.js

```
import ToastPlugin from 'vue-toast-notification';
import 'vue-toast-notification/dist/theme-bootstrap.css';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const options = {
    position: "bottom-right",
    duration:3000
  };

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ToastPlugin, options);
});
```

/composables/useToast.js

```
import { useToast } from "vue-toast-notification";

export default function () {
  return useToast();
}
```

Now your composable should be auto imported all over the app and you should be able to call the toast in your pages or components like this:

```
const toast = useToast();
toast.success('successful message');
```